# After a golang range copy all items point to the last item of the src slice

Tags: go, range

After I copy all items from a slice (src) into a new slice (dst) all items in dst point to the last item of src.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    src := []string{"a", "b", "c"}
    dst := []*string{}
    for _, val := range src {
        dst = append(dst, &val)
    }

    for i, s := range dst {
        fmt.Printf("%v - %v\n", i, *s)
    }
}

>>> 0 - c
>>> 1 - c
>>> 2 - c
```

Why aren't "a" and "b" copied into the dst slice?

Comment: I won't mark it as duplicate since you already got some good answers, but see: https://golang.org/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is simple, but counter intuitive in terms of what you would expect of the `range` statement.

The variable `val` is instantiated only once and holds the **value** of `src[i]` in every iteration. It does not has the actual pointer to `src[i]`. Instead the value of `src[i]` is copied to the memory that is assigned to `val`. By taking the pointer of `val` you get exactly that, and not the pointer to `src[i]`.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    src := []string{"a", "b", "c"}
    dst := []*string{}
    for _, val := range src {
        dst = append(dst, &val)
    }

    for i, s := range dst {
        fmt.Printf("%v - %v - %p\n", i, *s, s)
    }

    //modify only contents of first index
    *dst[0] = "hi val"

    for i, s := range dst {
        fmt.Printf("%v - %v - %p\n", i, *s, s)
    }
}

>>>>
0 - c - 0x1040a120
1 - c - 0x1040a120
2 - c - 0x1040a120
0 - hi val - 0x1040a120
1 - hi val - 0x1040a120
2 - hi val - 0x1040a120
```

While in hindsight this is obvious - `for _, val` -> := <- `range src` - it can can bite you in the ass if you are unaware of it, so therefore this warning.

PS. this also applies to `src` as a map.

Answer (score 5):

Adding to @RickyA's answer.

To achieve what you were trying to do you need to do:

```
for i := range src {
    dst[i] = &src[i]
}
```